# Disable or hide error message in PhpStorm when connection timed out (MySQL server)?

Tags: phpstorm

Is there any way to disable or hide this error message by default in PhpStorm when connecting to my MySQL database to view a table for example (any other interactions too when connection timed out)?

[image]

I've unchecked `Show error notifications in editor` which may be for another part of this IDE, because this doesn't affect that this error message will be displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to have the option to disable it.